# Adding information to a legend with Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, legend

I have a plot, of an group of applications uplink/downlink, the distribution is shown with CDF, and I want to improve the plot by adding more information in its legend, for example, I want it to show me the number of point of each variable,
for this code, instead of showing me:

```
--- Uplink
___ Downlink
```

I want to see this:

```
--- Uplink(54)
___ Downlink(88)
```

where 54 is the number of plotted points in this Uplink and where 88 is the number of plotted points in this Downlink

Here is my code that I want to improve:

```
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab
#---Reading from a csv file
def getColumn(filename, column):
    results = csv.reader(open(filename), delimiter="\t")
    return [result[column] for result in results]
#---the cdf Function
def cdf(inputList):
    outputList = []
    inputList.sort()
    for i in range(0, len(inputList)):
        outputList.append( [inputList[i], (i+1.0)/len(inputList)] )
    return outputList
#--getting the data i want from the csv file
fgfS=getColumn("dataFG.csv",2)
bgfS=getColumn("dataBG.csv",2)
fgifS=getColumn("dataiFG.csv",2)
bgifS=getColumn("dataiBG.csv",2)
#---the points to plot:
fgfS1=[]
fgfS2=[]

for i in cdf(map(float,fgfS)):
    fgfS1.append(i[0])
    fgfS2.append(i[1])

bgfS1=[]
bgfS2=[]
for i in cdf(map(float,bgfS)):
    bgfS1.append(i[0])
    bgfS2.append(i[1])

fgifS1=[]
fgifS2=[]

for i in cdf(map(float,fgifS)):
    fgifS1.append(i[0])
    fgifS2.append(i[1])

bgifS1=[]
bgifS2=[]
for i in cdf(map(float,bgifS)):
    bgifS1.append(i[0])
    bgifS2.append(i[1])


fig2, (ax2,ax02) = plt.subplots(1,2, sharey=True)
labels=('Uplink','Downlink')
fig2.suptitle('Applications Down/Up link', fontsize=20)
#******************    
ax2.set_title('App 1')
#ax2.set_xlabel('seconds')
ax2.set_ylabel('CDF')
ax2.grid(True)
ax2.plot(fgfS1,fgfS2, 'b')
ax2.plot(bgfS1,bgfS2, 'c')
ax2.set_xscale('log')
ax2.legend(labels,loc='best')
#******************
ax02.set_title('App 3')
ax02.set_xlabel('seconds')
ax02.set_ylabel('CDF')
ax02.grid(True)
ax02.plot(fgifS1,fgifS2, 'b')
ax02.plot(bgifS1,bgifS2, 'c')
ax02.set_xscale('log')
ax02.legend(labels,loc='best')
```

So I was thinking to add len(bgfS1) for example but i still didn t figure out where and how....

Comment: Your question doesn't concern CDF, and you provide way too much irrelevant code. Basically what you want is to display additional info with the legend - that's a valid question, and you will increase your chances of getting an answer quickly if your answer and code are concise and to the point, not just the entirety of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just append it to your `labels` list components, which determine what will be eventually displayed.

So you'd want:

```
ax2.legend(['{} ({})'.format(lab, cnt) for lab,cnt in izip(labels, (len(fgfS1), len(bgfS1)))],loc='best')
```

(This is essentially just appending the count to each of the labels)